how do I change the properties of the selected element in the UIList?
so, i have the ui list and many properties for each element witch is added to it. The idea is that when the user selects an object in the list, its properties are displayed at the bottom. He can change them for each element. The problem is that I can't get access to these properties in any way, more specifically to objects that have these properties. Here my ui lis:
class OBJECT_UL_my_list(bpy.types.UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname, index):
        obj = item
        row = layout.row()
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT'}:
            if item:
                row.prop(obj, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon, event=False)
                row.prop(obj, "weight", text="")

        elif self.layout_type == 'GRID':
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            row.prop(text="", icon_value=icon)

but I still have 4 properties for each object, and putting them all in a row in the list of items would be just awful, so they should be under the list. Like so:

On the screenshot, other properties from another propertyGroup are marked in red, but I need the properties of the selected object from the list. That is, I need to change these properties and the changes are recorded in the uilist

You would have to draw the elements after the UI list depending on the active element of the UI list.
The active element index is the active_propname of the active_dataptr which is an index of an element of the collection propname of dataptr which you set when you draw the UI list.
For example:
dataptr: bpy.context.object
propname: 'vertex_groups'
active_dataptr: bpy.context.object.vertex_groups
active_propname: 'active_index'
The active element: bpy.context.object.vertex_groups[bpy.context.object.vertex_groups.active_index]

does it also work with custom properties?

Thank you very much!

It works for bpy.types.AnyType which is any possible data.
